# Разные шаблоны для laravel

Tags: laravel

Как реализовать выбор шаблона в laravel?
Например админ заходи в панель и выбирает понравившийся шаблон из представленных.

В голове только одно решение:

В папке `resource>view` создаем разные папки с шаблонами
В бд хранить название этого шаблона
А в контроллерах каждый раз доставать из бд название шаблона и подставлять его

```
return view($name_themes.'home');
```

Есть более простое решение?

Comment: Есть много более правильных решений через иземение пути к шаблонам в зависимости от темы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если тема не кардинально меняет весь интерфейс, то достаточно менять лейаут во вьюшках (в нем же подключаются все css и js) название темы верно вы подметили, хранить в БД у юзера.

```
@extends('layouts.'.$name_themes)
```

если же нужно менять кардинально все, то тогда менять и лейаут и вьюшки

```
return view($name_themes.'.home');
```